# XNA 4.0 2D Camera With Cursor Active

Tags: c#, xna, camera, cursor, 2d

I am pretty new to XNA framework For now I can do drawing, animations and so, But I have encountered a problem with **Camera** displaying **cursor**.

I want to achieve a 2D game where you use cursor as main controller (selecting, moving on map and so). I want the camera to be controlled by cursor Right-click and drag.

I have created very simple logic for moving it, but it's not working.
Anytime I press RButton and drag it, camera is working well.

The problem pop up when do it again. Whole View resets to initial position. I guess the problem is with mouse position relative to world.

I am adding my camera Class

```
class TCCamera : IDrawable
{
    public Matrix transformation;
    Viewport viewport;
    Vector2 centre;

    public TCCamera(Viewport vport)
    {
        viewport = vport;
        this.centre = new Vector2();
    }
    public void LoadContent(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager Content)
    {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Matrix Translate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.transformation;
        }
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mstat = Mouse.GetState();



        if (mstat.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.centre.X = mstat.X;
            this.centre.Y = mstat.Y;
            transformation =  Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0));
        }

    }


}
}
```

And also the Cursor Class

```
class TCCursor : IDrawable
{
    Texture2D tex;
    public Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bBox;

    public TCCursor()
    {
        this.pos = new Vector2();
        this.bBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        tex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cursor");
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(tex, bBox, Color.White);
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState value = Mouse.GetState();
        this.pos.X = value.X;
        this.pos.Y = value.Y;
        this.bBox.X = value.X;
        this.bBox.Y = value.Y;
    }

}
```

And also I am drawing as

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, 
            BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            null, null, null, null, camera.Translate);
```

I still cannot completely understand the concept of World and View Matrices and their Math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I have found the solution using inverse matrices.
I have found this extremly useful: [Tutorial XNA Camera](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237979-2d-camera-in-xna/)